# Can I pay for my wife's hospital bill from my HSA?

Tags: united-states, debit-card, hsa, billing

My wife is on a different insurance plan than me.  Different provider and all.  I have a HSA that my employer and I contribute to every paycheck.  Can I pay for my wife's hospital bill with my HSA debit card?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can pay for your wife's medical bills out of your HSA.

From IRS [Publication 969](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p969/ar02.html#en_US_2014_publink1000204081), Distributions from an HSA:

> Qualified medical expenses are those incurred by the following persons.
>
> 1. You and your spouse.
> 2. All dependents you claim on your tax return.
> 3. Any person you could have claimed as a dependent on your return except that:
>
> > a. The person filed a joint return,
> >       b. The person had gross income of $3,950 or more, or
> >       c. You, or your spouse if filing jointly, could be claimed as a dependent on someone else's 2014 return.